# Rails routes error. No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hello im doing tutorial from Rails Book and get into some troubles.

While im trying to log in with my username and password im getting the following error:

Routing Error

No route matches [POST] "/sessions/new"
Try running rake routes for more information on available routes.

This is my route file config.

```
ZomfgShop::Application.routes.draw do
  get "admin/index"
  get "sessions/new"
  get "sessions/create"
  get "sessions/destroy"

  resources :users
  resources :orders
  resources :line_items
  resources :carts

  get "store/index"

  resources :products do
    get :who_bought, on: :member
  end

  resources :products

  root to: 'store#index', as: 'store'

  resources :line_items do
    #member do
    # post 'decrement'
    #end
    post 'decrement', on: :member
  end

  get 'admin' => 'admin#index'

  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

You have controller instead of resources for the :sessions routes.

```
  resources :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end
```

Answer (score 0):

Try replacing

```
get "sessions/new"

get "sessions/create"

get "sessions/destroy"
```

with

```
resources :sessions
```

make sure you have a views/sessions/new.html.erb file (under views/devise/ if using devise)

and make sure you have this in sessions_controller.rb if you aren't using Devise

```
def new
end
def create
end
def destroy
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you guys, changed my routes.rb file to this and my routing fine is working fine once again!

```
ZomfgShop::Application.routes.draw do
  get 'admin' => 'admin#index'

  controller :sessions do
    get 'login' => :new
    post 'login' => :create
    delete 'logout' => :destroy
  end
  scope '(:locale)' do
    resources :users
    resources :orders
    resources :line_items
    resources :carts
    get "store/index"
    resources :products do
      get :who_bought, on: :member
    end
  root to: 'store#index', as: 'store'
end

resources :line_items do
  #member do
  # post 'decrement'
  #end
  post 'decrement', on: :member
end
```

Comment: If you put 4 spaces between each line of code, it will be nicely formatted and readable.